# Set feature "preview" in BibDesk to generate preview in APA format

Tags: bibdesk

BibDesk has a preview feature that allows you to visualize the typeset output of the reference you just entered.

I would like to know how to make BibDesk to typeset the preview using APA style.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It's not necessary to sign your questions (as [there is already a box with your username below it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures)) or to begin them with a greeting. Also, as long as your question is not about MathJaX we are pretty forgiving. ;)

Answer (score 2):

In the BibDesk preferences there is a Preview panel.  Choose `apalike` as the BiBTeX style:

[image]